# Python connect to random VPNs fastly but without using TOR

Tags: python, python-requests, request, ip

I should connect to random IP addresses (or change IP address if have a way) instantly I should connect like tor but without using tor because of tor is blocked. Have any way?

Example of what I want with using tor:

```
import requests

proxy = {'http': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150'}

requests.get("https://www.example.com/", porxies=proxy)
```

Note: I should do in a while loop, so it shouldn't be for just one time

Comment: *"should connect like tor but without using tor because of tor is blocked"* - well, a SOCKS5 proxy is nothing like TOR.

Comment: I'm using tor on socks5 :D

Comment: Ah, so you have Tor running and would like to use it through the exposed proxy? How do you have Tor running if you say that it is blocked? I am confused. You should explain in more detail.

Comment: I just want to send request with difrent IP address but without TOR :)